# Lambda function ends before DynamoDB get ends in Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having a small issue with the DynamoDB client. I'm developing a skill which needs to fetch some data from a DynamoDB table. The table and the data are there. For some reason I'm unable to trigger the call (I presume the code ends before the async callback is able to retrieve the data). I'm following the official documentation here. I must be missing something. Can you help me out? Here is the portion of the code that references the issue:

```
"use strict";

const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
var constants = require('./constants');

...
...
...

let readDynamoItem = function(callback) {
    // callback("if uncommented I send this successfully");
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    let params = {
        Key: {
            "topic": {
                S: "car"
            }, 
            "element": {
                S: "ford"
            }
        }, 
        TableName: "brands"
    };

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        // callback("if uncommented I never see this");// never reached
        if (err) {
            callback("response with err");// never reached
        } else {
            callback("response with data");// never reached
        }
    });
};

const guessAttemptHandlers = {
    'Correct': function(guess) {
        ...
        if (left === 0) {
            ...
            readDynamoItem.call(this, (function(result) {
                this.response.speak("Tmp result is " + JSON.stringify(result));
                this.response.listen("Please say yes, no or stop.");
                this.emit(":responseReady"); 
            }).bind(this));
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    if (constants.debugMode) {
        console.log("====================");
        console.log("REQUEST: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        console.log("====================");
    }

    let alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = constants.appId;
    alexa.registerHandlers(newSessionHandlers, startGameHandlers, guessModeHandlers, guessAttemptHandlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

I also checked the CloudWatch logs but, there are no issues or errors. I just get a response that ends the session, which is not what I'm aiming for.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By default, your lambda function will timeout in 3 seconds. You can check the value of Duration in the CloudWatch logs to confirm if this really is a case of lambda ending before the dyanamodb call.

Alexa's request will timeout after 10 seconds so you can try increasing the timeout for your lambda function upto 10 seconds from the aws console and check if it fixes your issue.

Comment: I just checked my timeout and it is set to 7 seconds. The function really ends the session at 2 or 3 seconds at most. Sometimes even faster.

Comment: @VictorVelchev Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I switched to boto3 and my issues were fixed.